# Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate cmdlet results in: Key not valid for user in specified state

Tags: azure, import, certificate, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to import a .pfx certificate to an Azure keyvault but am having some issues.

```
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "SecHash03" -Name "CodeSigning" -FilePath "\path\to\my\cert.pfx"
```

Results in:

```
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate : Key not valid for use in specified state.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName SecHash03 -Name " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.ImportAzureKeyVaultCertificate
```

I'm requesting this cert from an Enterprise CA using certreq from a machine in the same domain as the CA. There is no password required to import the cert. Plan was to then upload that cert to the aforementioned Azure keyvault.

I tried using the Azure portal to import this cert and that works fine; import and usage both works well. So this is not an issue with Roles as suggested in another similar Stackoverflow answer ([Importing certificate to Azure Key Vault: Key not valid for use in specified state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460672/importing-certificate-to-azure-key-vault-key-not-valid-for-use-in-specified-sta)).

Please advice!

Comment: Could you make sure you use the same user account in azure portal and powershell?

Comment: Do you Import this PFX cert with a password using Azure portal?

Comment: Any update on your side? May I know if the reply is helpful?

Comment: Hi @NancyXiong, yes your reply was very helpful. So sorry for not responding sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, when you import a pre-existing .pfx file cert to Azure key vault, you need to provide a password which is used for protecting the cert as you need to export the cert within **the Private Key** and include all certificates in the certificate path if possible.  For example,

```
# Export the cert to a PFX with password
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password!" -AsPlainText -Force
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert "cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($cert.Thumbprint)" -FilePath C:\temp\cert2.pfx -Password $password

# Upload to Key Vault
Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName noel-temp -Name cert2 -FilePath C:\temp\cert2.pfx -Password $password
```

Alternatively,

> If you use a supported CA, you can even configure Key Vault to enroll
>   for certificates on your behalf. No leaking of keys! For simplicity,
>   the policy in these examples will be set to generate self-signed certs
>   from Key Vault.

```
# Have Key Vault create the certificate with a simple policy
$policy = New-AzureKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SubjectName "CN=mycluster.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com" -IssuerName Self -ValidityInMonths 12
Add-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName noel-temp -Name cert1 -CertificatePolicy $policy

# Download the secret (private key information) associated with the cert
$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName noel-temp -Name cert1
$secretBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($secret.SecretValueText)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\cert1.pfx", $secretBytes)

# Import the certificate to CurrentUser\My
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\temp\cert1.pfx -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My -Exportable
```

You could get more details from these two links:

[Importing Certificates to Key Vault](https://www.noelbundick.com/posts/importing-certificates-to-key-vault/)

[Manage certificates via Azure Key Vault](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/manage-certificates-via-azure-key-vault/)

Comment: Hi @Nancy, you were correct. Sorry for responding so late. I confirmed with a MS support rep that password is required when using that cmdlet.